# Error trying to use 'restore with MySql' on DataGrip

Tags: mysql, dump, datagrip

I'm getting the following error while trying to dump a .sql with data grip, using 'restore with mysql'

`mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'database=dbname'.`

[image: print from the error]

I tried changing the mysql path to bin/mysql, however I get a invalid path error message

Comment: have you tried it without the double quotes

Comment: Yes, my coworker was able to perform the exact operation on datagrid without getting the error message, I don't understand why I'm having this error

Comment: then use single quotes instead

Comment: I solved it by reinstaling mysql-server and setting the path to mysql to "/bin/mysql", there was also a problem that my sql file was corrupted, but fortnualy I had a backup of it. Application is up and running now